# How do I change the email address that Google Cloud Platform alerts go to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I received an email from Google Cloud Platform about one of my projects, with subject line:

Action required: Problem with your Google API project

I'm wondering how I can change these emails to redirect them to another user in my company instead of me? I have scoured the Google Cloud Platform settings and I can't find anything that looks like it would determine where these mails are routed. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4):

There is a new feature since the last answer. In GCP you can manage the most of those notifications by setting "[Essential Contacts](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/managing-notification-contacts)"

It is currently in Preview state, but better than nothing :-)

Answer (score 3):

Project owner(s) receive these notification from GCP. If you want someone to receive notification for your project you can assign him/her the [Owner Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_roles) in your project IAM. A workaround to stop receiving notification is to remove yourself from the owner role assigned to your email, which will mean you will also lose some access in the project for creating and managing resources.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this might be the case and went ahead with that assumption, but it really helps to have confirmation!

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I am glad the my answer helps you. I really appreciate if you can upvote my answer please.

Comment: You bet! I don't have enough "reputation" yet to see my vote recorded, but, it said it did count, so hopefully that's happened!